# Why am i able to require in "src", but not in "core" directory in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have have the following project structure:

--fourth (my project folder)

---core

----core.clj

----mycore.clj

core looks like this:

```
(ns core.core)

(require '[core.mycore :refer [myhello2]] :verbose)
(println "hi")
```

mycore looks like this:

```
(ns core.mycore)

(defn myhello2 []

  (println "hi")
  )
```

If i evaluate core.clj, i get the following error:    Could not locate mycore__init.class, mycore.clj or mycore.cljc on classpath.

If i do the same and i just switch the "core" directory to "src", it works. What can i do, to make it work?

I tried to put
`{:depths ["core"]}` in deps.edn, but nothing changed.

But my deps.edn is empty: {}

Comment: You should be requiring `core.mycore`, not just `mycore` on its own. `src` is the root of the namespace; `src/core` is not.

Comment: (assuming "fourth" is the name of your project, then, properly following convention would have you be creating `fourth/src/core` as the directory that `core.clj` and `mycore.clj` with namespaces `core.core` and `core.mycore` go in; but to know which structure is appropriate to your particular project, we'd want to see your `deps.edn` with enough content to reproduce the issue ourselves).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i corrected the questions, could you check please? Is it possible to do require ..core or add core to clathpath?

Comment: `"src"` is usually added automatically to the classpath. If you really want your sources directory to be named `"core"`, then you have to add it to the classpath yourself. How exactly - depends on what you're using to manage your dependencies.

Comment: You'll be happier, long-term, if you build projects the way your tools want you to rather than fighting them on matters of personal preference -- adjust your preferences to suit the tools and you get a benefit of everyone else's projects looking/working the same way yours do, so there's no retraining habits when you move onto projects you don't personally own yourself.

Comment: Getting back to actually answering the question, though... Where did you find `:depths` in the documentation? That's not the parameter I see it recommending to adjust the root of the tree.

Comment: (did you mishear someone talking about "deps"? That's for describing which libraries to pull down from the Internet, not where to find things in your source tree).

Comment: Please don't use `(require ...)` in a source file.  Use `(ns ... (:require ...))` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://clojure.org/guides/tools_build, you want to use `:path`, not `:depths` (which I've never heard of / don't know to be valid at all) to specify the locations in your source tree from which to search for items.

```
{
  :paths ["."]
}
```

...means that `core.mycore` will be looked for in `./core/mycore.clj` instead of `./src/core/mycore.clj` (as is the case with the default `:paths ["src"]`).